# NTLM authen not available after installing MS Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, ntlm

After installing MS Exchange Server 2013 the SMTP service is running. However when telnetting the host I get 'AUTH' after 'EHLO', rather than 'AUTH NTLM'. I have checked off "integrated Windows authentication' in the security tab. How can I enable NTLM authentication?

I have tried Client Frontend servername (port 587) and Default Frondend servername. (port 25)

Here is the telnet log:

```
ehlo
250-myhost Hello
250-SIZE 37748736
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 XRDST
```

Comment: @mgorven how you did that? Thanks.

Comment: Indent each line.

Comment: @mgorven I see, cool :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your security tab?  Single server?